# Fisher Information. Density function.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, fisher-information

I'm reading about Fisher's information. However, a question arises. What is the difference between the density function $$f(x,\theta)$$ and the same density function when composing with the random variable X?$$f(X,\theta)$$

$$I(\theta)=E_\theta\left[-\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial \theta^2}\ln f(\theta;X)\right].$$

Comment: $f(X,\theta)$ is a random variable, whence it makes sense inside the expectation.

Comment: oh, thanks. But other than that, can the density function be interpreted the same way?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: Is there a difference besides the second being a random variable?

Comment: Convention is $X$ for random variable and $x$ for a realisation of $X$. Under this convention $f(x)$ is the pdf/pmf of $X$ evaluated at $x$. And being a function of $X$, $f(X)$ is a random variable.